# Can't create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

The quickest way to explain the problem is to show a screenshot.  Here's what I'm getting whenever I try to set up a provisioning profile on Apple's developer site:

[image]

Note the "Error" under the "Status" column.  This is currently happening whenever I try to create any sort of profile (development, distribution, ad-hoc), the certificate goes immediately from the "Pending" state to the "Error" state.  Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

I'm confident that I'm configuring the profile correctly when I go to create it.  Basically I'm following the same steps that have worked several times over in the past (it's pretty hard to do something invalid when setting up a profile), but for some reason it's giving me the screen shown above.

Any information on similar issues and how they were fixed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112180/re-installing-iphone-certificates-giving-me-an-error :) More precisely this: http://devforums.apple.com/message/680221

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's a general outage on Apple's part then.

Comment: check your certificate-->Development your .csr file valid data  more than current date.

Comment: Well, certainly no more feeling like there's anything I can be doing to fix this problem, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

many people meet this problem since yesterday: https://devforums.apple.com/message/680208